# how can i get index no.of clicking element?

Tags: javascript

my UL have the 5 Li, in the li it has the a href, while i click on the a, it has to show the it's index no.from the ul. example if i click 3rd li, then it should alet 3. for that i am using this function:

```
var titles = document.getElementById('bigscreen-titles');  if(titles){
    var links = titles.getElementsByTagName('a');

    for(i=0;i<links.length;i++){
        links[i].onclick = function(){
            alert(i);
        }
    }
}
```

but it always show 5. even if i click on 1st li, it show the same, any correct way.. please

Comment: Is there any chance that you except one of the given answers?

Answer (score 1):

the solution goes as follows:

```
if(titles){
    var links = titles.getElementsByTagName('a');

    for(i=0;i<links.length;i++){
        links[i].onclick = function(currentIndex){
            return function () {
                alert(currentIndex);
            }
        }(i)
    }
}
```

The outer function is called immediate function. It means the function is executed immediately after definition. So it returns a new function, the inner function. These function gets a reference to the `currentIndex`. This is called a closure.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is due to something called 'closures' and basically happens because the alert function is running at some point after the loop has finished, and 'i' is 5 at this point.

You should be able to solve this by way of a simple change...

```
if(titles){
    var links = titles.getElementsByTagName('a');

    for(i=0;i<links.length;i++){
        links[i].onclick = function(index){
           return function() {
               alert(index);
           }
        }(i)
    }
}
```